# When do we need to show a function is well-defined?

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, continuity, cauchy-sequences

Proposition: Let $A$ be a dense subset of $B$. Let $f$ be a uniformly continuous function from $A$ to a complete metric space $C$. Then $f$ has a unique extension to a continuous function from $B$ to $C$.

My attempt, only on showing $f$ has an extension to a continuous function from $B$ to $C$:

Since $(A,d)\subseteq (B,d)$ such that $\overline{A}=B$, then $\forall b\in B$, given any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists $a\in A$ such that $a \in S_{\epsilon}(b)$. Due to Theorem 36, there exists a sequence $\{\alpha_n\}$ that converges to $b$. By Theorem 43, $\{\alpha_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. By Theorem 51, since $f$ is continuous, $\{f(a_n)\}$ is also a Cauchy sequence in $C$. Since $C$ is complete, $\{f(\alpha_n)\}$ converges to some $\gamma \in C$; Hence, $f(b)=c$.

*But, I was told that this attempt at a proof is insufficient to prove the claim since I still need to show that $f$ is well-defined; which is also what the proof from Kaplansky's text has done.*

> **Question 1:** I do not understand why proving $f$ is well-defined is necessary due to my understanding that since $\{a_n\}$ arbitrary in the set $S$ of sequences that converges to $b$, then we no longer need to consider another sequence in $S$. But apparently, I am wrong. Why?
>
> **Question 2:** Why is it allowed to assumed that the sequence at (16), seen below has a subsequence converging to $c$?

[image]

Comment: If you don't show that $f$ is well defined you won't be able to show that the function you have defined on $B$ is continuous. The answer to your second quesion is if you pick the 1st, 3rd, 5th ... elements in the sequence you get a desired subsequence.  As far as your comment below is concerned, you will have to write down the proof of continuity to convince yourself that you have a problem.

Comment: Why? Is $\{a_n\}$ not arbitrary?

Comment: I know picking elements from the sequence $\{f(x_i)\}$ would get me a subsequence. My question was why can we assume that its subsequence converges to $c$. To emphasize, my question was regarding its convergence to $c$. Thanks.

Comment: See the definition of $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is my comment as an answer:

When you set $f(b)=\lim f(a_n)$, you have chosen the limit given by that subsequence. Your friend might have chosen a different sequence $(\alpha_n)$ with $\alpha_n\to b$ and would like to set $f(b)=\lim f(\alpha_n)$. You both have the same definition only if $\lim f(a_n)=\lim f(\alpha_n)$, i.e. if your definition does not depend on the arbitrary choice of a sequence converging to $b$
 that you made. You know that for any arbitrary $a_n\to a$,$(f(a_n))$
 converges; you do not yet know that all of the sequences $(f(a_n))$ converge to the same limit.

Comment: Just to clarify, at the end you meant "we do not yet know all sequences $(f(a_n))$ converges to the same limit."?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: Isn't this a proof of *uniqueness*? The question was about the extension being *well-defined*. That's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it should be necessary to show that our constructed extension is well-defined, at least not because of different choices of sequences.

Define *one* extension $\bar f : A \to C$ by the following procedure:
For every $a \in A$ set $\bar f(a) = f(a).$ For every $b \in B \setminus A$ take *one* sequence $(a_k) \subset A$ converging to $b$ (such a sequence exists by denseness of $A$) and set $\bar f(b) = \lim f(a_k).$ Here we need to show that the limit exists (this you might call well-definedness), but right now we don't need to show that it does not depend on the choice of sequence.

Now we have an extension. We have two steps left: 1) to show that $\bar f$ is *continuous*, 2) to show that it is *unique*. One way to show the latter might be to show that it doesn't depend on the choices of sequences.

Am I wrong? Do I miss something?

Comment: I think you're right. I just happened to ask a question relating to the continuity of the extension of $f$ which of course requires that $\overline{f}$ is well-defined at $b\in B\setminus A$.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: If $(a_n)$ and $( \alpha_n)$ are sequences whic both converge to $b$, then we know that the sequences $(f(a_n))$ and $f(\alpha_n))$ are convergent. In order to show that $f(b)$ is well-defined, we have to show that

$$\lim f(a_n)= \lim f(\alpha_n).$$

Q2: $(f(a_n))$ is a subsequence of the sequence in $(16)$ and $\lim f(a_n)=c$.

Comment: I know how to show that $f$ is well-defined. I just want to know why. Thanks!

Comment: When you set $f(b)=\lim f(a_n)$, you have chosen the limit given by that subsequence. Your friend might have chosen a different sequence $(\alpha_n)$ with $\alpha_n\to b$ and would like to set $f(b)=\lim f(\alpha_n)$. You both have the same definition only if $\lim f(a_n)=\lim f(\alpha_n)$, i.e. if your definition does not depend on the arbitrary choice of a sequence converging to $b$ that you made. [You know that for any arbitrary $a_n\to a$, $f(a_n)$ converges; you do not yet know that all of these sequences converge to the same limit].

Comment: @Kusma: I will accept your explanation if you post it as an answer. Thanks.